# How do I allow logging in from two different locations in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My app allows a user to log in from two different places, the header and the new session page. The new session page logs a user in and redirects them to the correct page, but the home pages just reloads the home page without redirecting the user or logging them in.

This is my sessionscontroller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_back_or feed_user_path(user)
    else
      session[:user_id] = nil
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-large btn-info" %>
    <% end %>
```

Code in my _header.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :session, :url => {:controller => "sessions", :action => "new"} do |f| %>
   <div class="home-login form-group">
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %>
    </div>
  <div class="home-login form-group">
<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>
  </div>
<div class="form-group home-login">
<%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn-info" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This is what shows up in the terminal

> --- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
>   utf8: ✓
>   authenticity_token: AegIbI8c1TIddIBPVWTt/B2CBoCAgbJxL+NWDe782Cc=
>   session: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
>     email: ****** @ ******
>     password: ****
>   commit: Log in
>   controller: pages
>   action: home

EDIT****

This is my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

Home is a static page in my pages controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end
end
```

EDIT****

This is my SessionsHelper

```
module SessionsHelper

  def signed_in?
    !!session[:user_id]
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def current_user=(user) # set current user
    @current_user = user # session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user?(user) # get current user
    user == current_user
  end

  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end
end
```

EDIT****

Routes

```
sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                   sessions#create

new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)               sessions#new

session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)               sessions#destroy
```

Comment: Post the code for your ApplicationController and HomeController

Comment: Would it help if I said I'm using simple forms?

Comment: What gem are you using for authentication? And can you also paste `SessionsHelper`?

Answer (score 0):

try changing your form_for tag to direct it to the create action with a method of post.  something like this:

```
<%= form_for :session, url: session_path, method: 'post', action: 'create' do |f| %>
```

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"} missing required keys: [:id] is the error I get when I try this.

Comment: so it seems like you got to the correct controller action?, and you are hitting a new bug.  check your server messages to see, but the only place I see a were destroy would be called is in the redirect_back_or method, which is in the create action of the session controller

Comment: Never mind that last comment, I was using session_path when I should have been using sessions_path. Sorry. But even with the update I still get the same result. I updated my terminal listing

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference with where do you put your login form unless you refer to any controller-specific data there. I don't see that, so you should be good to go with just copying the exact same `form_for` call that actually produces working results. At least I don't see anything that prevents doing this.

And the problem is the action. `new`. Wrong. It's `create`. "New" is a display page for the form (and uses GET because of that), the actual form's action (data send path) is "create" (that uses POST). HTTP method is picked from the routes, execute `rake routes` to verify that they are correct.

A form is not bound to a page it's on. Instead, it has its own path, that should accept input data from the form.

Comment: If I use the new.html.erb form, I get the same problem. Changing for "new" to "create" doesn't help either.

Comment: Ok. I put the form in another page and I was able to log in. I'm not sure if I should have mentioned this before but the form is in a partial for the header. Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The ERB form was wrapped in an HTML form. That was causing the problem.